# SQL - Get rows where all values X of Column A = value B

Tags: sql

I'm wondering how I would go about getting all the rows of data where all the fees of a given transaction (defined by TransactionID) are Price = 0.00.

So for all rows with the same TransactionID, if the Price in all of those rows is 0.00, then return a row with that UserID, UserName, and TransactionID.

*Note, every Transaction could have 1 or more Fees, so for every fee the price has to equal 0.00 for the row to be returned.

It's easier to explain with an examples so...

Given this table of data:

```
+--------+----------+---------------+-------+-------+
| UserID | UserName | TransactionID | Price | FeeID |
+--------+----------+---------------+-------+-------+
|      1 | bill     |          1111 | 0.00  |     1 |
|      1 | bill     |          1111 | 7.00  |     2 |
|      2 | bob      |          2222 | 0.00  |     2 |
|      3 | sarah    |          3333 | 0.00  |     1 |
|      3 | sarah    |          3333 | 0.00  |     2 |
|      4 | jill     |          4444 | 8.00  |     1 |
|      5 | jack     |          5555 | 3.00  |     1 |
|      5 | jack     |          5555 | 7.00  |     2 |
|      1 | bill     |          6666 | 0.00  |     1 |
|      1 | bill     |          6666 | 0.00  |     2 |
|      1 | bill     |          6666 | 0.00  |     3 |
+--------+----------+---------------+-------+-------+
```

The query should return:

```
+--------+----------+---------------+
| UserID | UserName | TransactionID |
+--------+----------+---------------+
|      2 | bob      |          2222 |
|      3 | sarah    |          3333 |
|      1 | bill     |          6666 |
+--------+----------+---------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try converting your English explanation (which is very clear) to SQL. Then, post the SQL you came up with so we can help you understand where you are having trouble.

Comment: Google and learn about the WHERE EXISTS() function.

Comment: Ok I'm working on it right now and I'll post an update in a little bit. @TabAlleman thanks for the tip, I'll look that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't all clear to me but from the output it looks like you just need to use a `having` clause:

```
select UserID, UserName, TransactionID 
from table
group by UserID, UserName, TransactionID 
having sum(price) = 0 and max(price) = 0
order by TransactionID
```

This query gives you the same result as your example.

The extra `and max(price) = 0` in the having clause makes sure that the sum isn't 0 because there are values that counteract each other (like 1, -1).

Comment: Except that this wouldn't exclude a case where a price of 1 is offset by a price of -1.

Comment: Yup that did it.  I'm just learning SQL so I didn't know about HAVING.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, that indeed true. The query could use a correlated not exists predicate too. Then it would be correct.

Comment: @TabAlleman It would be nice to calculate for negatives, but in this cause it isn't a problem because the data is validated beforehand to make sure the price is always >= 0

Comment: @jpw If you could update your answer with the not exists predicate for future viewers that would just be icing on the cake :)

Comment: @Max I added a check that should cover the the case above. If the both the sum and the max value is 0 there can't exists any value that is not 0. If I got the logic right - it's been a long day so not 100% sure ;)

Comment: @jpw I just verified your edit by adding values of 1 and -1 which cancel each other out, and the max(price) = 0 filters them out correctly.  Thanks again!