# An interesting tricky filter (don't know how to describe it in title)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table is like this:

```
Item   Subitem    Progress  
1      101        Complete  
1      102        Pending
1      103        Pending
2      201        Complete
2      202        Complete
```

I want to SELECT the Items whose Subitems are all Complete --- in this case, Item #2. Any idea how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: In other words, you want all the Items where there does NOT EXIST a row with Progress<>'Complete'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Get rows where all values X of Column A = value B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481213/sql-get-rows-where-all-values-x-of-column-a-value-b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So many ways:

```
select Item from T group by Item
having min(Progress) = max(Progress) and max(Progress) = 'Complete'
```

or

```
having count(case when Progress = 'Complete' then 1 end) = count(*)
```

or

```
having count(case when Progress = 'Complete' then null else 1 end) = 0 /* handles nulls */
```

or

```
select distinct Item from T t
where 'Complete' = all (select Progress from T t2 where t2.Item = t.Item)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you basically want all items that don't have any Subitems in Pending status

Assuming the table you have shown is the SubItems table and there is another Items table...

```
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE ITEMID NOT IN (SELECT ITEMID 
                     FROM SubItems 
                     WHERE Progress != 'Complete')
```

Comment: You probably want `distinct`.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary on the Main select.  I guess it might be more efficient to have it in the sub query.

Comment: You get two rows of Item 2 without it.

Comment: I'm assuming the Items table is a different table.